# How do I make a for loop that will print an Array of strings in order in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

I am trying to make a for loop to print out all of the following strings to go into the println statement below but cannot figure out how to get the for loop to print the Array. I keep getting the error 'cannot find symbol.' There will be a scanner that allows for user inputs after each println statement.

```
 public static void Real() {
    String[] sequence;
    sequence = new String[4];
    sequence[0] = ("first");
    sequence[1] = ("second");
    sequence[2] = ("third");
    sequence[3] = ("fourth");
    int number;
    for (number = 0; number <= sequence(); number++ ) {
        System.out.println("Input your " + sequence + " lap time");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of syntax errors present in your code, also, **method** name in java should start with a lowerase.

Code below should do the work.

```
 public static void real() {
   String[] sequence;
   sequence = new String[4];
   sequence[0] = "first";
   sequence[1] = "second";
   sequence[2] = "third";
   sequence[3] = "fourth";
   int number;
   for (number = 0; number < sequence.length; number++ ) {
     System.out.println("Input your " + sequence[number] + " lap time");
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't print an array just by referring to its name in a print statement, you need to loop through all the elements and print element at each index. You access an element using the syntax **array[index]**.

You need to loop from 0 to the last index, I think what you're trying to get from **sequence()** is the size of the array. To get the size of array you need to use **array.length**

So your code should look like this :

```
public static void Real() { 
    String[] sequence; 
    sequence = new String[4];
    sequence[0] = ("first"); 
    sequence[1] = ("second"); 
    sequence[2] = ("third"); 
    sequence[3] = ("fourth"); 
    int number; 
    for (number = 0; number < sequence.length; number++) { 
        System.out.println("Input your " + sequence[number] + " lap time"); } }
```

Answer (score 0):

use `number<sequence.length` instead of `number <= sequence()`

and

use `sequence[number]` instead of `sequence` inside **system.out.println()**

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void Real(String a[]) {
    String[] sequence;
    sequence = new String[4];
    Scanner input= new Scanner(System.in);

    sequence[0] = ("first");
    sequence[1] = ("second");
    sequence[2] = ("third");
    sequence[3] = ("fourth");
    int number;
    for (number = 0; number <4 ; number++ ) {
        System.out.println("Input your " + sequence[number] + " lap time");
        System.out.println("Input");
        variable = inupt.nextDatatype();
    }
}
```

this is the answer after what i understood.
i don't know about this by the way sequence();

Answer (score 0):

How about using for-each loop?

```
for (String s : sequence)
            System.out.println("Input your " + s + " lap time");
```